# Jquery show/hide table rows

Tags: jquery

I want to be able to show/hide the rows in a table using jquery. Ideally I want to have buttons above the table to sort the table with.

i.e [Show rows with id:black] [Show rows with id:white] [Show all rows]

I have searched all over but cannot find a solution. Anyone know how i can do this with jquery and make it cross browser compatible?

Thanks (Code below)

```
<table class="someclass" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" summary="bla bla bla">
<caption>bla bla bla</caption>
<thead>
  <tr id="black">
    <th>Header Text</th>
    <th>Header Text</th>
    <th>Header Text</th>
    <th>Header Text</th>
    <th>Header Text</th>
    <th>Header Text</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr id="white">
    <td>Some Text</td>
    <td>Some Text</td>
    <td>Some Text</td>
    <td>Some Text</td>
    <td>Some Text</td>
    <td>Some Text</td>
</tr>
  <tr id="black">
    <td>Some Text</td>
    <td>Some Text</td>
    <td>Some Text</td>
    <td>Some Text</td>
    <td>Some Text</td>
    <td>Some Text</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Your code is invalid - you can't have duplicate `id` attributes. I would suggest changing them to `class` instead.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Change your black and white IDs to classes instead (duplicate IDs are invalid), add 2 buttons with the proper IDs, and do this:

```
var rows = $('table.someclass tr');

$('#showBlackButton').click(function() {
    var black = rows.filter('.black').show();
    rows.not( black ).hide();
});

$('#showWhiteButton').click(function() {
    var white = rows.filter('.white').show();
    rows.not( white ).hide();
});

$('#showAll').click(function() {
    rows.show();
});
```

---

```
<button id="showBlackButton">show black</button>
<button id="showWhiteButton">show white</button>
<button id="showAll">show all</button>

<table class="someclass" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" summary="bla bla bla">
    <caption>bla bla bla</caption>
    <thead>
          <tr class="black">
            ...
          </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="white">
            ...
        </tr>
        <tr class="black">
           ...
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

It uses the [`filter()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method to filter the rows with the `black` or `white` class (depending on the button).

Then it uses the [`not()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/not/) method to do the opposite filter, excluding the `black` or `white` rows that were previously found.

---

**EDIT:** You could also pass a selector to `.not()` instead of the previously found set. It may perform better that way:

```
rows.not( `.black` ).hide();

// ...

rows.not( `.white` ).hide();
```

...or better yet, just keep a cached set of both right from the start:

```
var rows = $('table.someclass tr');
var black = rows.filter('.black');
var white = rows.filter('.white');

$('#showBlackButton').click(function() {
    black.show();
    white.hide();
});

$('#showWhiteButton').click(function() {
    white.show();
    black.hide();
});
```

Comment: @Paul: You're welcome. I just updated my answer. The code at the very bottom will perform the best as long as you're not adding/removing rows dynamically.

Comment: Patrick, I have run into a small problem. Your code works great, but I was zebra striping the table using jquery "$(".someclass tr:even").addClass("alt");" However after the filter is applied the striping gets messed up. Is there a way to reapply the stripoing after filter?

Comment: @Paul: Whenever you hide/show some rows, you should reapply that code, but use the `:visible` selector to only affect those rows that are now visible. `$(".someclass tr:visible:even").addClass("alt");` If that gives you trouble, try flipping it around `:even:visible`. I don't remember the proper order, if any.

Answer (score 4):

The filter function wasn't working for me at all; maybe the more recent version of jquery doesn't perform as the version used in above code. Regardless; I used:

```
    var black = $('.black');
    var white = $('.white');
```

The selector will find every element classed under black or white.
Button functions stay as stated above:

```
    $('#showBlackButton').click(function() {
           black.show();
           white.hide();
    });

    $('#showWhiteButton').click(function() {
           white.show();
           black.hide();
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/corrected-b5fe953c76d4b82f7e63f1cef1bc506e.php

```
<span id="black_only">Show only black</span><br>
<span id="white_only">Show only white</span><br>
<span id="all">Show all of them</span>
<style>
.black{background-color:black;}
#white{background-color:white;}
</style>
<table class="someclass" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" summary="bla bla bla">
<caption>bla bla bla</caption>
<thead>
  <tr class="black">
    <th>Header Text</th>
    <th>Header Text</th>
    <th>Header Text</th>
    <th>Header Text</th>
    <th>Header Text</th>
    <th>Header Text</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr id="white">
    <td>Some Text</td>
    <td>Some Text</td>
    <td>Some Text</td>
    <td>Some Text</td>
    <td>Some Text</td>
    <td>Some Text</td>
</tr>
  <tr class="black" style="background-color:black;">
    <td>Some Text</td>
    <td>Some Text</td>
    <td>Some Text</td>
    <td>Some Text</td>
    <td>Some Text</td>
    <td>Some Text</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
<script>
$(function(){
   $("#black_only").click(function(){
    $("#white").hide();
    $(".black").show();

   });
   $("#white_only").click(function(){
    $(".black").hide();
    $("#white").show();

   });
   $("#all").click(function(){
    $("#white").show();
    $(".black").show();

   });

});
</script>
```

Comment: Your code is invalid too... you can't have duplicate `id` attribute values!