# How do I show/hide rows in a table and change text/link to reflect this change

Tags: php, jquery

I am getting data from a database that contains some rows of data which is archived data. I'm using php to get data and storing the data in entity objects.

To reduce database calls, I want to be able to display all the rows except the archived data when the page is created but have a link on the page that will change from 'show archived' to 'hide archived' which toggles the archived data on and off respectively.

The data is displayed in a table.  I am new to jquery and have found lots of articles but there seems to be a bug when showing and hiding in different browsers and am now very confused about the best way to do this.  I need to support most browsers but am using jQuery 1.10.

```
<table width='100%' border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4" class="mytable">
    <tr>
        <th>Product</th>
        <th>Supplier</th>
        ....
    </tr>
    <?php
    if ($product->getDateArchived() != NULL) {
         echo "<tr class=\"archivedrow\">";
    } else {
          echo "<tr> ";
    } ?>
    <td><?= $product->getProductName() ?></td>
    <td><?= $supplier->getSupplierName() ?></td>
    ....
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6686377/jquery-show-hide-table-rows

Comment: The first thing you want to do when working with jQuery is just concentrate on the HTML.  Take the results of the PHP and save it as HTML.  How the HTML is generated is not important.

Comment: If you're trying to reduce the database load by showing only non-archived posts you'll need to make a second call via ajax or page load to get the archived posts

Answer (score 0):

If on load you are supposed to hiding archived rows.

Call this in document ready

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('tr.archivedrow').hide();
});
```

Now on show archived button just call

```
     $('tr.archivedrow').show();
```

And on hide archived button just call

```
     $('tr.archivedrow').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this. I'll share with you three.

---

**Print out all rows in the HTML but hide/show via jQuery**

You mentioned you wanted to reduce database load by only returning the non archived rows at first.  This solution doesn't reduce the database load on page load as it gets all of them and just uses css to hide them

**PHP/HTML**

```
<?php

    // ... db connection code etc.

    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM table");

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
?>        

    <div class="<?php echo $row['archived'] ? 'archived' : 'notarchived' ?>">
        <!-- all your html stuff here -->
    </div>

<?php } ?>

<a id="toggle-archived" href="#">Toggle archived</a>

<?php

    // ... clean up db/result close code etc.
```

**CSS**

```
.archived {
    display: none;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {
    $('#toggle-archived').click(function() {
        $('.archived').toggle();
    });
});
```

---

Another way to do it is to have the page refresh and change the sql query on refresh

**PHP/HTML**

```
<?php

    // ... db connection code etc.

    $showArchived = isset($_GET['show_archived']) && $_GET['show_archived'];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM table";

    if (!$showArchived) {
        $sql .= " WHERE archived = 0";
    }

    $result = $mysqli->query($sql);

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
?>        

    <div>
        <!-- all your html stuff here -->
    </div>

<?php } ?>


<?php if ($showArchived) : ?>
    <a href="/">Hide archived</a>
<?php else: ?>
    <a href="/?show_archived=1">Show archived</a>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php

    // ... clean up db/result close code etc.
```

---

The third way would be to change the content via ajax.  The could would be similar to those above but you would have your javascript look something like:

```
$(function(){
    $('#toggle-archived').click(function(){
        $.post('page.php', data, function(resp) {
            $('#dataTable').html(resp);
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone.  I didn't want to reload the page as the data is retrieved from various databases and tables and is therefore expensive to run just to toggle viewing data I already have access to.  Its working using the following code:

**CSS:**

```
tr.archivedrow {
    display:none;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".showarchived").on("click", function(event) {
        if ($(this).hasClass("displayed")) {
            $(this).html("Show Archived");
            $(this).removeClass("displayed");
        } else {
            $(this).addClass("displayed");
            $(this).html("Hide Archived");
        }
        $(".myTable .archivedrow").toggle();
    });


});

</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<a class="showarchived" href="#">Show Archived</a>
<table width='100%' border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4" class="mytable">
<tr>
    <th>Product</th>
    <th>Supplier</th>
    ....
</tr>
<?php
if ($product->getDateArchived() != NULL) {
     echo "<tr class=\"archivedrow\">";
} else {
      echo "<tr> ";
} ?>
<td><?= $product->getProductName() ?></td>
<td><?= $supplier->getSupplierName() ?></td>
....
```