# How do I show/hide a hidden - by default - table row with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to show/hide a table row that is hidden by default. Here is an snippet of what I am doing:

```js
function showHidePatientSupportedCont(val) {
  alert(val == '0');
  if (val == '0') {
    $('#pattient_supported_cont').removeAttr('style').show();
  } else {
    $('#pattient_supported_cont').hide();
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".btn-0, .btn-1").click(function() {
    showHidePatientSupportedCont($(this).data('val'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr id="patient_supported_cont" style="display: none">
    <td>
      text text text
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button data-val="0" class="btn-0">Click 0</button>
<button data-val="1" class="btn-1">Click 1</button>
```

But for some reason the row never gets displayed. I have read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6686377/jquery-show-hide-table-rows) and I am doing exactly as in the accepted answer. What I am missing here?

PS: [Here is a Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/reynierpm/gtacn6qw/5/) for you to play as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in both of your identifiers:

```
  if (val == '0') {
    $('#pattient_supported_cont').removeAttr('style').show();
  } else {
    $('#pattient_supported_cont').hide();
  }
```

to:

```
  if (val == '0') {
    $('#patient_supported_cont').removeAttr('style').show();
  } else {
    $('#patient_supported_cont').hide();
  }
```

There is an extra 't' in 'patient' =)

Comment: @ReynierPM haha we all do it, staring at code too long we miss the simple stuff!